# Nodejs function is working only once

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, mongoose

I have a function called `UpdateDocument.js` and I have to run this function `when I do request`. It's only running once. After first request, it's not updating document. I have to refresh page but this is not why I want.

I'm requesting from `client` side and running function in `server` side.

```
socket.emit('UpdateDocumentRequest', ....);
```

UpdateDocument.js :

```
var users  = require('./datas/user');    
exports.UpdateDocument = function(app, passport, io) {   
io.on('connection', function(socket){ 
  socket.on('UpdateDocumentRequest', function(data) {
         //console.log(data);
        socket.emit('UpdateDocumentRequest__return', { last_balance: last_balance });

        var query = {....};
        users.update(query, { ...},   function (err, statu) { 
    });

});
}
```

In `server.js`

```
UpdateDocument.UpdateDocument(app, passport, io);
```

Console : 
As you can see, they have different dates.

```
{ user: '',
  btc_balance: '0.00008630',
  betAmount: '0.00000002',
  betPayout: '2',
  betProfit: '0.00000002',
  betTime: '2014-08-24T05:17:45.328Z' }
{ user: '',
  btc_balance: '0.00008630',
  betAmount: '0.00000002',
  betPayout: '2',
  betProfit: '0.00000002',
  betTime: '2014-08-24T05:17:47.225Z' }

{ user: '',
  btc_balance: '0.00008630',
  betAmount: '0.00000002',
  betPayout: '2',
  betProfit: '0.00000002',
  betTime: '2014-08-24T05:17:49.871Z' }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are sending more than one request from the client? It might help to explain in more detail how to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I added a console log, last 3 requests.

Comment: Any messages in console on the client? Looks like you're missing a closing ); at least?

Comment: I've checked now but there is no missing anything.